# How do I use put e.g. before multiple cites in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, citing

In bibtex for latex, I use `\cite{foo2012,bar2013,abc2014}` and it outputs:

> (Foo, 2012; Bar 2013; ABC 2014)

When i use `\cite[e.g.]{foo2012,bar2013,abc2014}`, it outputs:

> (Foo, 2012; Bar 2013; ABC 2014 e.g.)

**Without the use of `natbib`, how do I get**:

> (e.g. Foo, 2012; Bar 2013; ABC 2014)

Sorry the bib style from the conference organizers just can't play well with `natbib`. The latex template is from http://naacl.org/naacl-pubs/

Comment: Instead of linking to an external site, please write up a [small/minimal example](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you're still wondering:

```
\cite[e.g.,][]{foo2012, bar2014}
```

I guess the magic is the extra brackets.

Comment: Any idea why I'd get an error: "Citation `[' on page 2 undefined"? My header includes "\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}"